# Folders view through some out of box webparts

Tags: web-part

I have a Document library with a view which shows some folders and files in it. Now I want to show this Document library view in a page and I tried using a page viewer webpart but the problem here is it shows whole page (left navigation, top navigation...) and I am interested to show only the part of the view on this Library. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the List view on the same Web (aka sub-site) that is pretty easy, simply use the same Web Part catalog and you should find the equivalent List View Web part (automatically added) in the list.

You are however attempting to show the View on another sub-site, you would need to export the web part via SharePoint designer (in the ribbon you'll find "To Site Gallery") or to a file after making your changes.

This phase being done you could easily import the same web part in any page - either Wiki page or Web part pages into a web-part zone.

Comment: Hi Marius, Thanks for your reply. I tried to open the page with SP designer and downloaded the webpart from the page and imported it to my new page. here the issue is it only shows regular view not filtered folder view which it shows in old page or in SP designer.